# Selecting by expression n features with lowest attribute value

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer in QGIS. The points have a distance attribute to a fixed point. I would like to select the three points with the shortest distance by an expression.

I want to do it by expression because I want to use this expression in some code I will use in PyQGIS.

The minimum function doesn't work over different features, so I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I am not a expert in python but, I think what you are looking for here is a if than statement